# Microsoft Word show 2 printers but "Devices and Printers" show only 1 printer, I want to erase the hidden printer

Tags: windows-10, printer

["MSWord" **vs** "Devices and Printers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1pR.png)

In the left half of the image, "MSWord" shows 2 printer selection.

1. The **red circled printer** is in an error state
2. The **blue circled printer** is also in an error state but it actually exist in "Devices and Printers"

In the right half of the image, "Devices and Printers" shows only 1 printer

1. The **blue circled printer** which is a copy (`1 コピー`) of the **red circled printer**

I want to erase the **red circled printer** but how can I erase it since it is no where in sight: e.g. "Devices and Printers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can removing it (accidentally stumbled on a solution that works currently) from **Windows 10 Home**:

1. Open a **NotePad**
2. Press `Ctrl + P` to show the [Print Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uON5.png)
3. The problematic printer (the hidden or the ghost printer) will appear
4. `Select` and then `right click` the problematic printer
5. From the right clicked context menu, select `Delete(D)` (`削除(D)`)
6. [Printer Deletion Confirmation Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNFps.png) will appear, so click the `Yes(Y)` (`はい(Y)`) button
7. Now the problematic printer should be [gone from Print Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tikn8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Run `printmanagement.msc`.

This interface will show all printers.
You may right-click a printer and select Delete.

---

For Windows Home, Print Management is not available, so look here:

- *Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners*, click a printer's entry
  and then "Remove device"
- Use `regedit` and navigate to following keys and search for the ghost
  printer under the following keys:

  - For 64-bit Windows:
    `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers`
  - For 32-bit Windows:
    `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows NT x86`
- Using PowerShell run as Administrator:

  ```
    Remove-Printer -Name "hP4FBE12"
    Remove-PrinterDriver -Name "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"   (if required)
  ```

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it did not work. I opened **Run** with ```Win + R``` and then typed ```printmanagement.msc``` ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQu0.png)) but an ```can not find``` error occurred ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOLaO.png)). The images are Japanese, but the error says "cannot find 'printmanagement.msc'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again". Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: It exists in `C:\Windows\System32\printmanagement.msc`. Note: Add images in your post, not in comments.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow & superuser so thank you for teaching me about common practice. I will from now on. Also thank you for your prompt reply. I checked but unfotunately it is not there. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I am using Windows 10 Home since on this site it mentions that it is not available: [How to Open Print Management in Windows 10 / 8 / 7](https://www.top-password.com/blog/open-print-management-in-windows/)

Comment: I added a section for Windows Home in my answer.

Comment: I accidentally stumbled on [a solution](https://superuser.com/a/1640123/1285923) that worked for now. Unfortunately I could no longer test your solution which may have worked. I thank you for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`printmanagement.msc` may not be an available command for all users. This might help work around the issue: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-cannot-find-printmanagement-msc-in-windows-10

Comment: With your tip, I found this page: [How to Open Print Management in Windows 10 / 8 / 7](https://www.top-password.com/blog/open-print-management-in-windows/). However, from the article, I also found that on Windows 10 Home, **Print Management** doesn't seem to be available.